# What does: "The procedure entry point StiCreateInstanceA could not be located in the dynamic link library STI.dll" mean?

Tags: windows-vista, user-accounts, virus, trojan, file-corruption

I keep getting this message on start up: "The procedure entry point StiCreateInstanceA could not be located in the dynamic link library STI.dll" (only on one of my user accounts on my computer). That user account had a trojan virus (which I managed to get rid of with my scan/internet security) but since removing it, I've had this error message on start up (after I log in) A second trojan was removed too, and after a thorough scan (using power eraser) 2 suspected bad files were removed, but it still shows up. I read that the "STI.dll" was the virus file (so I shouldn't restore it) and that "wpbt0.dll" might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It may not have been the virus, as that method [appears valid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). On Windows 2008 (the server version of Vista basically) you can install the Desktop Experience package, which gives you Aero and some other nice GUI / Vista effects and that installs the STI.dll. Perhaps your virus took it out, or over rote the file with a bad copy. I would try to copy it off of your Vista disk and see if it corrects the issue.

wpbt0.dll appears to me to be a Trojan downloader. You might still have something... Try another AV software, MBAM, Microsoft Security Essentials are both good choices.

Comment: Thanks! I scanned again and also searched for wpbt0.dll and nothing turned up. But the problem with the the STI.dll is that I don't have a  Vista disc (everything came pre-loaded). Do you know where I could download it?

Comment: try downloading Recuva and see if it will recover sti.dll from C:\Windows\System32
http://www.piriform.com/recuva